# Vlookup row and column, softcode col_index_num

Tags: excel

Is there a formula to vlookup row(normal vlookup) + a condition to lookup a column?

For example the row I am lookup up is "TOTAL" and the column I want to lookup is "JULY 2020" , this will change based on cell input. However this sheet always is changing and months are added. I dont want to hardcode the col index num.

[image]

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `INDEX/MATCH/MATCH`.

Comment: If you're always looking for the last (right most) column value you could use: =OFFSET(C2,0,COUNTA(D2:Y2)) adjusting the Y2 to accommodate maximum expected column letter maybe plus a couple. Also assuming there won't be any empty values. If empty values are possible you could adjust the COUNTA to count the column headings row instead.

Comment: Sorry I will always  be looking for a particular month.

Answer (score 0):

Is the total always in the same row? If so, then a simple hlookup formula would work. For the table range, just extend as far right as you want.

Here's a solution if the total is always in the same row, for example:

[image]

***EDITS MADE AFTER HERE***

If the "total" could be different rows (like row 4 or 5), then use index-match-match formula:

```
    =INDEX(E2:HDD4,MATCH(A5,D2:D5,0),MATCH(B4,E1:DD1,0))
```

[image]

But I'm a little confused on how a total could be in rows 4 or 5. Do you still have one row that says "total"? If you have two rows for total, then maybe add another row for "total", and make it the bottom-most value of rows 4 and 5. If that's the case, then you could stick with the hlookup formula.

So in this case, in row 7 (totaltotal), create this array formula for each column:

```
    =INDEX(E1:E5,MAX((E1:E5<>"")*(ROW(E1:E5))))
```

Make sure to press CTRL-SHIFT-ENTER after entering the formula to make it an array. Then cell B5 would be the hlookup formula from before, but making it reference row 7 instead of row 4 this time.

```
    =HLOOKUP(B4,D:DD,7,FALSE)
```

Final Output:

[image]

Comment: Total row can change :( , thats the part i have trouble with. Total may be on row 4 or 5.